# Is there a way to set min-height of textview wrt to lines?

Tags: android, textview

Is there a way to set the min-height of a text view wrt to the number of lines. Let's say if I know that the text size is 20dp and the min-height should be such that it's equivalent to 3 lines of text then what should it be. Could be done by using line height or some hacks but I wanted to know if there's a legit way to achieve this?

Comment: try wrap_content

Answer (score 0):

You should add `TextView` height to wrap_content and ellipsize to end.

Answer (score 0):

```
android:minLines="3"
```

Comment: This does not work.

Comment: @JeffreyBlattman Can you please show me your layout code? as this works perfectly fine by me.

Comment: It's an empty `TextView` (no text set) within a `LinearLayout`.

Comment: @JeffreyBlattman See this screenshot ->[link](https://pasteboard.co/caosMBr8GlTN.png)